# closed set of $E^2$ (Euclidean space)

Tags: general-topology

> A set $X$ with a specified topology $\mathcal T$ on it is called a topological space, we denote it by $(X,\mathcal T)$.
>
> A subset $F \subset X$ is called a closed set of $X$ if $X-F$ is open in $X$.

Give an example of countable set $B$ such that $B$ is not a closed set of $E^2$ ( Euclidean space), then give an example of countable $C$ such that $C$ is a closed set of $E^2$ .

I dont't undertsand this topic, any hints or help so i can understand my lecture note. Thank you

Comment: Actually you must be more clear about **what exactly** you don't understand. Is it the term "Euclidean"? Is it the $2$ in $E^2$? Is it "countability"?...

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense, so not closed.

$\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ is countable and closed (and discrete too).

Answer (score 0):

I believe by $E^2$ you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,
$$A=  \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\} \ \ \ , \ \ \ B= \mathbb{N} $$
Now consider these sets $A,B$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $A$ is countable but not closed. $B$ is countable and closed.